# trigger is duplicating data

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to do this adding from storelte_notifications to storelte_usernotifications my notifications everytime the own systen make, but when my trigger try do insert them to the other table does it the first insert well , but the second one not , it also duplicating data  on my second table , how can I fix it? this is how my trigger looks like

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `storelte`.`user_notification`
AFTER INSERT ON `storelte`.`storelte_notifications`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO storelte_user_notifications 
SELECT storelte_notifications.user_id, NEW.id, NEW.timestamp,0
FROM storelte_notifications
```

[image: storelte_notifications_table]

[image: storelte_user_notifications_table]

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are selecting from - maybe this is what you intended

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `storelte`.`user_notification`
AFTER INSERT ON `storelte`.`storelte_notifications`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO storelte_user_notifications 
values (NEW.user_id, NEW.id, NEW.timestamp,0)
```